# PHP code turns file not result to HTML via jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some simple jQuery code

```
$.get( 'PHP/reverse.php', { input: text }, function( data )
    {
        $('#feedback').text( data );
    });
```

And here is the PHP code

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['input']))
{
    $string = $_GET['input'];
    echo strrev($string);
}
?>
```

Now when I click my button on the web page it should reverse the text given in the text field box, but if i input Egg it should print out ggE in the div below but what it actually prints out is this

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['input'])){$string = $_GET['input'];echo strrev($string);}?>
```

Does my PHP code have an error or am i doing it wrong?

UPDATE

I have now installed WAMPP and have installed my file in the directory

```
'C:/xampp/htdocs/amit/reverse.php'
```

When i click the button now, nothing is inputted to the div box but chrome tells me the header has

"hello" the text I inputted
so now the input is being given to the server, but nothing is returned, any reasons?

Comment: your server is not running i guess

Comment: looks like your php script isnt being executed just printed, is your server setup to execute `.php` files?

Comment: check if php is enabled and also check your file extensions.

Comment: I am using google chrome and running with --allow-file-access-from-files so how would i get the PHP to execute?

Comment: PHP is a server side language, you need to have a server or emulate one to execute it. You can use any server emulator as WAMP / LAMP

Comment: I now have XAMP, how would I go about putting my PHP file onto it and then reading it from there?

Comment: read the documentation, maybe...

Comment: Well I put the PHP file into the PHP folder and when I try and call it now, nothing happens at all. So something must be kinda working :)

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use this in javascript

```
<script>
function reverse(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QRdFc/

Also noting seems to be wrong in your code, just change your `{ input: text }` with `{ 'input': text }`

Comment: Using `$_REQUEST` can be dangerous (could open yourself to CSRF attacks if you are not careful when expecting POST data). The behavior of `$_REQUEST` is also dependent on the `request_order`/`variables_order` ini directive. **Always** use the more specific `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`, even in cases where you want to allow your input to come from both GET and POST.

Comment: Would prefer to use PHP

Comment: @Canvas do `{ 'input': text }`

Comment: I changed it to that $.get( 'C:/xampp/htdocs/amit/reverse.php', { 'input': text }, function( data )
  {
   $('#feedback').text( data );
  }); but still don't get a result :(

Comment: also try it with `$.get( 'PHP/reverse.php?input='+text, function( data )`